# .htaccess rewrite rules are refusing to take effect - any htaccess experts out there?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, centos6

I have got a wierd problem... htaccess rules seem to not be working

Here's my rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /index.php?view=$1&layout=$2 [NC]
```

It doesn't take effect no matter what I try. In theory I should be able to visit /my/test/ and see the content for index.php?view=my&layout=test

A rewrite rule later on in the page to force https:// does work, and I know the htaccess is being read by the server.

Server is a VPS on Centos 6

Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer - if anyone comes looking

The rule should read:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/ /index.php?view=$1&layout=$2 [NC]
```

(Remove the first / )